# I get combined rows when i use join query

Tags: mysql, join

I use the following query:

```
select * 
from TEST2 t1 join TEST2 t2 
where  t1.TID <> t2.TID 
  and t1.ST = t2.ST 
  and t1.SAL > t2.SAL 
  and t1.TR < t2.TR;
```

I have 16 attributes in my table. But when i fire the above query i get result of two rows combined in one row with 32 attributes.

I want to get the result as two different rows and not one row, i.e the combination of both in one row.

```
6|Mark|Murro|M|970|-3134|Denver|CO|80251|S|Y|70000|4|0|0|0|0    
2|Chunho|Black|M|719|-4662|Denver|CO|80290|M|N|60000|5|0|0|0
```

As shown above, both the rows get combined and comes as

```
6|Mark|Murro|M|970|-3134|Denver|CO|80251|S|Y|70000|4|0|0|0|0|2|Chunho|Black|M|719|-4662|Denver|CO|80290|M|N|60000|5|0|0|0
```

Table Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST2` (
  `TID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FN` text,
  `LN` text,
  `GD` text,
  `AC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PH` text,
  `CT` text,
  `ST` text,
  `ZIP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MS` text,
  `CH` text,
  `SAL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TR` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MTX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But i want them seperate
 Please help me out

Comment: can you add table schema?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `TEST2` (
  `TID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FN` text,
  `LN` text,
  `GD` text,
  `AC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PH` text,
  `CT` text,
  `ST` text,
  `ZIP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MS` text,
  `CH` text,
  `SAL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TR` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MTX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CTX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: what if you try `select t1.*  from TEST2 t1 ....` instead.

Comment: I get the results but i only get rows from t1 only . . not form t2.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you are really trying to do, but the following should implement your logic

```
select t.*
from test2 t
where exists (select 1
              from test2 t2 
              where t.tid <> t2.tid and t.st = t2.st and t.sal > t2.sal and t.tr < t2.tr
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from test2 t2 
              where t.tid <> t2.tid and t.st = t2.st and t.sal < t2.sal and t.tr > t2.tr
             );
```

Because you want both rows, it needs to check for the conditions in both directions.